# Show/Hide payment methods for various product categories in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So, I've seen example of how to unset payment gateways based on product category, such as this one (which works nicely):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 
'unset_gateway_by_category' );

function unset_gateway_by_category( $available_gateways ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return $available_gateways;
    if ( ! is_checkout() ) return $available_gateways;
    $unset = false;
    $category_ids = array( 11810 );
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $values ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );    
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {        
            if ( in_array( $term->term_id, $category_ids ) ) {
                $unset = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( $unset == true ) unset( $available_gateways['worldpay'] );
    if ( $unset == true ) unset( $available_gateways['ppec_paypal'] );
    return $available_gateways;
    }
```

In this instance, removing payment methods Worldpay and PayPal if any product with product category ID 11810 is in the cart.

But, it doesn't quite cover what I need.

So, if you have categories 1, 2, 3 and 4... along with payment methods a, b, and c.

Product category 4 can only use payment gateway c, and product categories 1,2 and 3 can only use payment gateways a and b.

If there are products from all categories in the cart (including category 4), then the above code would hide payment methods a and b, only leaving gateway c (works perfectly). But... how to unset gateway c, if the cart ***doesn't*** contain any products from category 4?

I think I need an elsif in there somewhere, but... I'm no php ninja, so would appreciate a little guidance.

Thanks in advance.

***UPDATE:***

The version below is the closest so far.

It hides the specialist gateway when there's no restricted products in the cart.
It hides the regular gateways when there's only restricted products in the cart.

However... if there's a mic of regular products AND restricted products... it hides all gateways.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 
'unset_gateway_by_category' );

function unset_gateway_by_category( $available_gateways ) {
if ( is_admin() ) return $available_gateways;
if ( ! is_checkout() ) return $available_gateways;
$unset = false;
$category_ids = array( 15, 166, 11810 );

/*This will dynamically map the payment gateway that need to be hidden for 
the specific category id*/
$category_payment_map = array(
    '15' =>  array('totalprocessing'),
    '166' =>  array('totalprocessing'),
    '11810' =>  array('worldpay', 'ppec_paypal')

    );

foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $values ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );    
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {        
            if ( in_array( $term->term_id, $category_ids ) ) {
                /*Based on Term Id, fetch the payment gateway that need to 
be hide from the $category_payment_map array*/
                $payment_gateway_ids =  $category_payment_map[$term->term_id];

                /*you can check here whether the $payment_gateway_id is an array or sin*/
                foreach ($payment_gateway_ids as $key => $payment_gateway_id) {
                    unset( $available_gateways[$payment_gateway_id] );
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways;
    }
```

I assume it needs some sort of rule that says, if cart has a mix of regular products and restricted products, then the restricted products rule applies and overrides the other rules?

Thanks

Comment: Replace  typo error `$$payment_gateway_id` by `$payment_gateway_id`

Comment: Fixed that. Thanks. However, all works well, until you have a cart that has a mix of regular and restricted products in it. In that scenario, it unsets all payment gateways.

Comment: Great to hear that it is working fine. Thanks

Comment: @MominIqbal No, you misunderstood, It's not working fine. It hides all gateways if you have both a regular and a restricted product in the cart.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is some wrong logical reperesentation in your code to unset the payment gateway.I have modified the code and provided the comment on modified code.

Please apply the code and let me know if it is working or not.
Hope your issue will be resolved for sure

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'unset_gateway_by_category' );

    function unset_gateway_by_category( $available_gateways ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return $available_gateways;
    if ( ! is_checkout() ) return $available_gateways;
    $unset = false;
    $category_ids = array( 11810, 11900 );

    /*This will dynamically map the payment gateway that need to be hide for the specific category id*/
    $category_payment_map = array(
                                   '11810' =>  array('worldpay', 'ppec_paypal'),
                                   '11900' =>  array('ppec_paypal')
                                );

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $values ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );    
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {        
            if ( in_array( $term->term_id, $category_ids ) ) {
                /*Based on Term Id, fetch the payment gateway that need to be hide from the $category_payment_map array*/
                $payment_gateway_ids =  $category_payment_map[$term->term_id];

                /*you can check here whether the $payment_gateway_id is an array or sin*/
                foreach ($payment_gateway_ids as $key => $payment_gateway_id) {
                    unset( $available_gateways[$payment_gateway_id] );
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways;
    }
```

Comment: this already on the right path, but if you'll review your code, at the end you're just returning `$available_gateways` without any change...

Comment: @Reigel Actually there is a typo in my code that i have updated now, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

@MominIqbal Little confused where "11900" came from in your example?

Might be my fault, in my explanation of the usage case.

To try and clarify. the usage case for this store, they have some CBD products and they must go through specialist payment gateway, so...

Just regular products = regular payment gateways (unset specialist gateway)
Just CBD products, **OR** mix of regular and CBD products = Specialist gateway (unset regular gateways).

Does that clarify what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: @MominIqbal Oh, wait... I think I understand...

$category_payment_map = array(
                                   '11810' =>  'worldpay',
                                   '11900' =>  'ppec_paypal'
                                );

So, I would put all product category ID's here, with each group followed by the payment methods I **don't** want to show for that group of categories?

Comment: For specific category, if you  want to hide multiple payment gateway, then you can use array format for the same. See my updated answer for the same

Comment: @MominIqbal I updated my original question, with the latest version of the code I'm using now. Unfortunately... it's now not hiding any gateways??

Comment: Please use the code now, there is a typo error. resolved @Del